# How to import Gmail's data into BigQuery

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, gmail

I want to import gmail's mail data into google bigquery.
But I do not know how to do that.
Could you tell me how to do it?

With the google apps script, can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could [assign Gmail logs to a BigQuery dataset](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7233312?hl=en). Keep in mind that this feature is available for [G Suite Enterprise](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7284269) and [G Suite for Education](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2856827) only.